# Alloy appcelerator not opening model database

Tags: android, sqlite, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I have an android alloy app that is using the sql adaptor in a model and a page that shows the data in the database.
This works.

However, I have added some code to delete all the rows in the only table in the db and this does not work. I use SQL instead of the model/backbone method of delete.
There is no error, but it seems that a new database is installed and is referenced by the delete and not the database used by the model.

I have tried using the same code from the sync adapter and variations of the same, all to no avail. For debug purposes I have replaced the delete with select code and this returns 0 rows. The database used by the model does contain rows.

The code is running in a service. The service also uses the model, so I am unsure as to whether it is relevant. I do not know if the model is keeping the database open and my open is failing silently and then creating a new database.

This is from the sync adaptor:

```
Ti.API.debug('Installing sql database "' + dbFile + '" with name "' + dbName + '"');
var db = Ti.Database.install(dbFile, dbName);

[DEBUG] Installing sql database "/trackit.sqlite" with name "trackit"
```

So I tried:

```
        Ti.API.debug('DELETING RECORDS');
        var db = Ti.Database.install("/trackit.sqlite", "trackit");
        // var db = Ti.Database.open('trackit');
        var rs;
        rs = db.execute('SELECT * FROM geo LIMIT 2;');
        Ti.API.debug('ROW COUNT: ' + rs.rowCount);
        while ( rs.isValidRow() ) {
            Ti.API.debug('COOKIE: ' + rs.fieldByName('id'));
            rs.next();
        }
        rs.close();
        db.close();
```

Which results in:

```
[DEBUG] COLLECTION SIZE: 0
[DEBUG] DELETING RECORDS
[DEBUG] ROW COUNT: 0
```

This is the model:

```
exports.definition = {
    config: {
        columns  : {
            "id"    : 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT',
            "lon"   : 'TEXT',
            "lat"   : 'TEXT',
            "time_" : 'TEXT',
            "now_"  : 'TEXT',
            "sent"  : 'BOOL'
        },
        defaults : {
            "sent" : 0
        },
        adapter  : {
            "db_file"         : '/trackit.sqlite',
            "type"            : 'sql',
            "collection_name" : 'geos',
            "idAttribute"     : 'id'
        }
    } // config

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hacking, it turns out that the collection_name should be the table name in the DB.
If db_file is used, installing the database creates the table "collection_name"
with column names and types from sqlite_master. ie not using the column_names
in the config of the model at all.